# Sheet-like fire in static render

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine

I want to make a static, not animated, render that looks kind of like this[image: this]

I think I can make the particle effects fine, but how do I make the material and texture look like this?

Comment: What have you got so far? Where are you stuck? Can you edit your question and post some screenshots of what you have achieved and what you need help with?

Answer (score -2):

You can find an image of the fire you are looking for and then in either photoshop or gimp, make the background transparent. then use the images as planes addon to add your fire into your scene. If you are wondering on how to make the rocket and the other hard surfaces thats a whole other topic. If you need any help with any of these steps just ask